# Xpath - Complex Path: How to find a element by referencing another element in a different parent?

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, xpath-2.0

So, I am facing a challenge,the thing is that, the webpage have a kind of list where there is some elements with Text and buttons to the side of them, like this:

[image]

The objective is to click on the buttons by referencing specific text (since the buttons Text is the same for all - "Button"), for example, to click only the buttons of "Element A" and "Element C"

I analyzed the HTML code and it's somewhat complex (at least to me) to try to target the xpath to my desired buttons

In essence, I would have a variable(s) that will store the string of the element Text ("Element A", "Element B"...) and then I should click on the buttons that are linked to them

The HTML code looks something like this (those strings are classes, just for reference, but they represent each node, like a div or span and the nested childs; sorry for the messy draw)

[image]

So, I am lost here, I tried to look for the parent and ancestor axes but really don't quite know how to properly implement the correct xpath,
Just as reference for that i am trying to accompplish, although I am sure it isn't the correct syntax

//span[(text()='Element A')]/(look for the master parent that encloses both the Element Text and Element Button)/(look for the "Button" text inside that parent which has the "Element A")

the thing is that, because there is many elements on the lsit, each master parent is different, that's why i am using the element Text ("Element A",  "Element B"...) to target the specific "Button"

Any suggestions or so is highly appreciated!
Maybe some tips to use the axes or predicates?

Thanks!

Actionable part of the HTML page, since putting all of the HTML code isn't that practical, it is huge
So for example, the Elements I was refering to are:

- Senua's Saga Hellblade 2
- Hellblade: Senua's Sacrifice & Senua's Saga
- Hellblade Senua's Sacrifice

Then I need to target the desired Buttons (with text "Share") based on which element text I am targeting, like: Hellblade Senua's Sacrifice

```
<div aria-busy="false" class="o8kakjsu role="listbox">
   <div class="a8s20v7p k5wvi7nf buofh1pr pfnyh3mw l9j0dhe7 du4w35lb">
      <div>
         <div class="rq0escxv">
            <div class="rq0escxv">
               <div class="rq0escxv ">
                  <div class="cbu4d94t e5nlhep0 aodizinl">
                     <div class="buofh1pr">
                        <div class="dati1w0a">
                           <div class="j83agx80 ">
                              <div class="knvmm38d">
                                 <h2 class="  " dir="auto">
                                    <div class="l9j0dhe7 stjgntxs ni8dbmo4" style="display: -webkit-box; -webkit-box-orient: vertical; -webkit-line-clamp: 2;">All</div>
                                 </h2>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="">
                  <div class="muag1w35 b20td4e0">
                     <div data-vc-ignore-dynamic="1" style="padding-left: 8px; padding-right: 8px;">
                        <div class=" a8c37x1j">
                           <div class="">
                              <div class="">
                                 <div class="">
                                    <a aria-label="Senua's Saga Hellblade 2  Sacrifice" class="oajrlxb2" tabindex="0">
                                       <div class="q9uorilb l9j0dhe7 pzggbiyp du4w35lb">
                                          <svg class="" data-vc-ignore-dynamic="1" role="none" style="height: 40px; width: 40px;">
                                             <mask id="jsc_c_4e">
                                                <rect cy="20" fill="white" height="40" rx="8" ry="8" width="40" x="0" y="0"></rect>
                                             </mask>
                                             <g mask="url(#jsc_c_4e)">
                                                <image x="0" y="0" height="100%"></image>
                                                <rect class="mlqo0dh0 georvekb s6kb5r3f" cy="20" fill="white" height="40" rx="8" ry="8" width="40" x="0" y="0"></rect>
                                             </g>
                                          </svg>
                                       </div>
                                    </a>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="ow4ym5g4 btwxx1t3 l9j0dhe7">
                                 <div class="gs1a9yip">
                                    <div class="" id="jsc_c_4d">
                                       <div class="j83agx80 cbu4d94t ew0dbk1b irj2b8pg">
                                          <div class="qzhwtbm6 knvmm38d"><span class="" dir="auto">Senua's Saga Hellblade 2  Sacrifice</span></div>
                                          <div class="qzhwtbm6 knvmm38d"><span class="" dir="auto">Group</span></div>
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="bi6gxh9e ozuftl9m aov4n071 l9j0dhe7 o8rfisnq" aria-labelledby="jsc_c_4d">
                                    <div class="bp9cbjyn j83agx80 btwxx1t3">
                                       <div class="">
                                          <div aria-label="Share" class="oajrlxb2 oo1teu6h " role="button" tabindex="0">
                                             <div class="c4xchbtz by2jbhx6">
                                                <div class="rq0escxv l9j0dhe7 "><span class="oi732d6d " dir="auto">Share</span></div>
                                             </div>
                                             <div class="" data-novc="1"></div>
                                          </div>
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div data-vc-ignore-dynamic="1" style="padding-left: 8px; padding-right: 8px;">
                        <div class="ue3kfks5 pw54ja7n uo3d90p7 l82x9zwi a8c37x1j">
                           <div class="scb9dxdr">
                              <div class="nqmvxvec  tvfksri0 aov4n071 l9j0dhe7">
                                 <div class="">
                                    <a aria-label="Hellblade: Senua's Sacrifice &amp; Senua's Saga" class="oajrlxb2 tabindex="0">
                                       <div class=" du4w35lb">
                                          <svg class="pzggbiyp" data-vc-ignore-dynamic="1" role="none" style="height: 40px; width: 40px;">
                                             <mask id="jsc_c_4g">
                                                <rect cy="20" fill="white" height="40" rx="8" ry="8" width="40" x="0" y="0"></rect>
                                             </mask>
                                             <g mask="url(#jsc_c_4g)">
                                                <image x="0" y="0" height="100%" ></image>
                                                <rect class="mlqo0dh0 georvekb s6kb5r3f" cy="20" fill="white" height="40" rx="8" ry="8" width="40" x="0" y="0"></rect>
                                             </g>
                                          </svg>
                                       </div>
                                    </a>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="btwxx1t3 l9j0dhe7">
                                 <div class="">
                                    <div class="" id="jsc_c_4f">
                                       <div class=" ew0dbk1b irj2b8pg">
                                          <div class="" dir="auto">Hellblade: Senua's Sacrifice &amp; Senua's Saga</span></div>
                                          <div class="qzhwtbm6 knvmm38d"><span class="hzawbc8m" dir="auto">group</span></div>
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="bi6gxh9e ozuftl9m aov4n071 l9j0dhe7 o8rfisnq" aria-labelledby="jsc_c_4f">
                                    <div class="bp9cbjyn j83agx80 btwxx1t3">
                                       <div class="">
                                          <div aria-label="Share" class=" tv7at329" role="button" tabindex="0">
                                             <div class="">
                                                <div class=""><span class=" g0qnabr5" dir="auto">Share</span></div>
                                             </div>
                                             <div class="" data-novc="1"></div>
                                          </div>
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div data-vc-ignore-dynamic="1" style="padding-left: 8px; padding-right: 8px;">
                        <div class="ue3kfks5 pw54ja7n uo3d90p7 l82x9zwi a8c37x1j">
                           <div class="">
                              <div class="nqmvxvec j83agx80 cbu4d94t bi6gxh9e tvfksri0 aov4n071 l9j0dhe7">
                                 <div class="">
                                    <a aria-label="AutoHotkey" class="oajrlxb2" tabindex="0">
                                       <div class="q9uorilb l9j0dhe7 pzggbiyp du4w35lb">
                                          <svg class="pzggbiyp" data-vc-ignore-dynamic="1" role="none" style="height: 40px; width: 40px;">
                                             <mask id="jsc_c_4i">
                                                <rect cy="20" fill="white" height="40" rx="8" ry="8" width="40" x="0" y="0"></rect>
                                             </mask>
                                             <g mask="url(#jsc_c_4i)">
                                                <image x="0" y="0" "></image>
                                                <rect class="mlqo0dh0 georvekb s6kb5r3f" cy="20" fill="white" height="40" rx="8" ry="8" width="40" x="0" y="0"></rect>
                                             </g>
                                          </svg>
                                       </div>
                                    </a>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="">
                                 <div class=" du4w35lb rj1gh0hx f10w8fjw pybr56ya">
                                    <div class="" id="jsc_c_4h">
                                       <div class="j83agx80 cbu4d94t ew0dbk1b irj2b8pg">
                                          <div class="qzhwtbm6 knvmm38d"><span class="" dir="auto">AutoHotkey</span></div>
                                          <div class="" dir="auto">Public group</span></div>
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="" aria-labelledby="jsc_c_4h">
                                    <div class="bp9cbjyn j83agx80 btwxx1t3">
                                       <div class="">
                                          <div aria-label="Share" class="oajrlxb2" role="button" tabindex="0">
                                             <div class="">
                                                <div class=""><span class="" dir="auto">Share</span></div>
                                             </div>
                                             <div class="" data-novc="1"></div>
                                          </div>
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
```

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: So, I really didn't want to overwhelm somebody, because it's a very long code, but if it helps, sure, added a sample code in the new edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your sample, this is what you should use. Example with "Hellblade: Senua's Sacrifice & Senua's Saga" :

```
//div[.="Hellblade: Senua's Sacrifice & Senua's Saga"]/following::span[.="Share"][1]
```

We look for the element which contains the string variable, then the first following element containing the text of the button.

So, this should do the trick for your page :

```
//span[.="Element A"]/following::*[.="Button"][1]
```

Comment: Woow it does work as well! If you can, please recommend some guides or videos you know that can help with this types of topics in Xpath, or some key concepts i can research further in this cases, thanks!

Comment: Start from here : https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp Also : https://riptutorial.com/xpath/topic/6171/location-paths-and-axes http://jean-luc.massat.perso.luminy.univ-amu.fr/ens/xml/figures/xpath/les-axes.png and if you need more details, check : http://www.utools.nl/downloads/XPathReference.pdf

Answer (score 0):

After a long research, I finally did it!
Watch this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a6B6XYbviRI

From there I was able to understand better the XPath logic and how to approach my challenge, the end Xpath is this one:

```
//span[(text()="Element A")]/parent::div/parent::div/parent::div/parent::div/parent::div//*[(text()="Button")]
```

For those who don't know Xpath, this is simply like taking a starting point (an element) and from there navigate precisely through (like parents or whatever is your case) and end up with the target element

If someone knows how to do it better, please! comment it out!